# I pushed 2 consecutive messages to the message queue, but they don't seem to be called consecutively

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to get the `scroll` event handler to ignore the event if the event was triggered by `$().animate()`. Here's what I tried:

```
var ignoreNext=false;
$('#element').on('scroll',function(){
    if(ignoreNext){
        ignoreNext=false;
        return;
    }
    $('#element').stop(true); // stop animation if the user triggered the scroll event
    $('#element').animate({
        scrollTop:...
    },{
        step:function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ // push to message queue right before the scroll event is pushed by $().animate()
                ignoreNext=true;
            },0);
        }
    });
});
```

JQuery triggers the `scroll` event after the `step` function has ran. The `setTimeout()` pushes the anonymous function to the end of the message queue. Immediately afterwards, JQuery pushes the `scroll` event to the end of the message queue.

I assumed the message queue would look something like this:

1. something irrelevant
2. something irrelevant
3. ignoreNext=true
4. scroll event (sets ignoreNext to false)
5. something irrelevant
6. something irrelevant

Thus, if one of the "something irrelevant" is a scroll event triggered by the user, then the animation should be stopped and restarted. However, this is not the case. Every time the scroll event is triggered (even by the user), `ignoreNext` is true. Therefore, the user cannot interrupt the animation.

Why does this happen and how can I allow the user to interrupt the animation?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to stop the default scroll event logic when element is scrolled via jQuery animate?

If so, you'd need to refactor it a little bit.

Firstly, abstract away all the logic that needs to be run on scroll event under 1 function

```
function defaultScroll(e) {
    console.log("scroll event ", e);
}
```

Then, a way to attach or detach this logic to scroll event, something like below, notice [namespaced events](https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/):

```
function attachScrollEvent() {
    $element.on("scroll.element", defaultScroll);
}

function detachScrollEvent() {
    $element.off("scroll.element");
}
```

Rest is just about finding out a way to call `attachScrollEvent` or `detachScrollEvent` whenever you need to enable or disable scroll event.

In your case, you'd want to call `detachScrollEvent` during `$('#element').animate({...})` and call `attachScrollEvent` once animation is complete. Something like below:

```
detachScrollEvent();

$element.animate({
    scrollTop: 200
}, 
{
    done: function() {
        setTimeout(attachScrollEvent, 0);
    }
});
```

Here's the full code (happy to comment it out if this is the sort of functionality you were after)

```
var $element = $("#element");
var $scrollButton = $(".js-auto-scroll");
var $output = $(".output");

attachScrollEvent();

$scrollButton.on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    detachScrollEvent();

    $element.animate({
        scrollTop: 200
    }, 
    {
        done: function() {
            setTimeout(attachScrollEvent, 0);
        }
    });
});

function attachScrollEvent() {
    $element.on("scroll.element", defaultScroll);
    var result = "<p>scroll event is <span class='green'>attached</span>.</p>";
    $output.html(result);
}

function detachScrollEvent() {
    $element.off("scroll.element");
    var result = "<p>scroll event is <span class='red'>detached</span>.</p>";
    $output.html(result);
}

function defaultScroll(e) {
    var scrollTop = e.currentTarget.scrollTop;
    var result = "<p>scrolled to: " + scrollTop + "px</p>";
    $output.html(result);
}
```

Oh and of course, link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/poLosmp9/2/)

---

#### Disable scroll animation when user scrolls

scroll animation can be stopped if the user scrolls by tapping into a bunch of events and seeing if the user initiated any of those (a bit hacky) something like below:

```
var allPossibleEventsThatCanStopAnimation = "scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove";

$element.on(allPossibleEventsThatCanStopAnimation, function(e) {
    if ( e.which > 0 || e.type === "mousedown" || e.type === "mousewheel") {
        $element.stop();
        detachScrollEvent();
        attachScrollEvent();
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/poLosmp9/3/

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to make it so that the user can stop the animation at any time. In the middle of the animation, if the user scrolls, the animation stops and a new animation is started. In your code, `defaultScroll` cannot be called while the animation is running.

Comment: You can stop scroll animation if user scrolls instead, by plugging in a bit of a hacky code. I've updated my answer and here's the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/poLosmp9/3/